# How to access an AMD module ("define") from ordinary JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I made a TypeScript code which was compiled like this:

```
define("Global/Global", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Global = (function () {
        function Global() {
        }
        Global.transition_time = 200;
        return Global;
    }());
    exports.Global = Global;
});
```

Now, in a classic "script.js" I'm trying to console.log() the "transition_time" value. But it tells me "Global is not defined".
I put a breakpoint in the console in the Global's function, but it's never triggered.

***EDIT :***

That's the Global's TypeScript code:

```
export class Global {
    static transition_time: number = 200;
}
```

Comment: Now, it could be nice if you also share the typescript code that created this? Are you requiring this module somewhere?

Comment: I added the small TS code, I tried to use that : "require(["Global/Global"]);" without any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an [AMD module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) there, so you'll need to use an AMD module loader such as [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) if you aren't using one already.  Then the proper syntax to access your module from `script.js` is like this:

```
require(["Global/Global"], function(Global_module) {
    console.log(Global_module.Global.transition_time);
});
```

The `require` function doesn't add anything to the global namespace; instead, you have to pass a callback that receives the module you asked for and does whatever you wanted with it.  Note the `Global_module.Global.transition_time`; `Global_module` is the name I gave to the variable that receives the entire module, and `Global` is the name of the exported class within the module.